# The strange .NET Core SDK 2.2.6 behavior

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2019

I learn the Azure certification and started to study a Azure tutorial, that uses the .NET Core in its demo project. Actually I have VS 2019 (only) and installed the latest to day .NET Core SDK (x64), as follows

```
C:\Learning\MS-Certif-20-487\AzureToolkit>dotnet --info
A compatible SDK version for global.json version: [1.0.4] from [C:\Learning\MS-Certif-20-487\AzureToolkit\global.json] was not found

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.2.6
  Commit:  7dac9b1b51

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.1.102 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.103 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.104 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.200 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.201 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.400 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.401 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.402 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.403 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.500 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.502 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.503 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.504 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.505 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.600-preview-009426 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.600-preview-009472 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.600 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.602 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.801 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.2.401 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.12 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.12 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.3-servicing-26724-03 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.12 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

C:\Learning\MS-Certif-20-487\AzureToolkit>dotnet new globaljson --sdk-version 2.2.401
A compatible SDK version for global.json version: [1.0.4] from [C:\Learning\MS-Certif-20-487\AzureToolkit\global.json] was not found
Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK from:
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409

C:\Learning\MS-Certif-20-487\AzureToolkit>
```

Please notice the last command, that asks to build a new global.json file with the latest SDK, it seems the `dotnet` does not recognize the SDK it just said it installed...

Finally my solution doesn't open in VS 2019 with the following error in the console:

```
C:\Learning\MS-Certif-20-487\AzureToolkit\AzureToolkitWalkthrough.csproj : error  : 
The project file cannot be opened by the project system, because it is missing some 
critical imports or the referenced SDK cannot be found.

Detailed Information:
Unable to locate the .NET Core SDK. Check that it is installed and that the version 
specified in global.json (if any) matches the installed version.
```

Visual-Studio-Code as well gives the following error, when trying to debug the project

> [info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
>           Omnisharp server running using Stdio at location 'c:\Learning\MS-Certif-20-487\AzureToolkit' on host 4820. A compatible
>   SDK version for global.json version: [1.0.4] from
>   [c:\Learning\MS-Certif-20-487\AzureToolkit\global.json] was not found
>   [warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
>           Failed to load project file 'c:\Learning\MS-Certif-20-487\AzureToolkit\AzureToolkitWalkthrough.csproj'.
>   c:\Learning\MS-Certif-20-487\AzureToolkit\AzureToolkitWalkthrough.csproj(1,1)
>   Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException: The SDK
>   'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web' specified could not be found. 
>   c:\Learning\MS-Certif-20-487\AzureToolkit\AzureToolkitWalkthrough.csproj
>   at
>   Microsoft.Build.Shared.ProjectErrorUtilities.ThrowInvalidProject(String
>   errorSubCategoryResourceName, IElementLocation elementLocation, String
>   resourceName, Object[] args)    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.ExpandAndLoadImportsFromUnescapedImportExpressionConditioned(String
>   directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement, List`1&
>   projects, SdkResult& sdkResult, Boolean throwOnFileNotExistsError)
>   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.ExpandAndLoadImports(String
>   directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement,
>   SdkResult& sdkResult)    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.EvaluateImportElement(String
>   directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement)    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.PerformDepthFirstPass(ProjectRootElement
>   currentProjectOrImport)    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.Evaluate(ILoggingService
>   loggingService, BuildEventContext buildEventContext)    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.Reevaluate(ILoggingService
>   loggingServiceForEvaluation, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings,
>   EvaluationContext evaluationContext)    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.ReevaluateIfNecessary(ILoggingService
>   loggingServiceForEvaluation, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings,
>   EvaluationContext evaluationContext)    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.Initialize(IDictionary`2
>   globalProperties, String toolsVersion, String subToolsetVersion,
>   ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, EvaluationContext evaluationContext)
>   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project..ctor(String projectFile,
>   IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String toolsVersion, String
>   subToolsetVersion, ProjectCollection projectCollection,
>   ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, EvaluationContext evaluationContext)
>   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection.LoadProject(String
>   fileName, IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String toolsVersion)    at
>   OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader.EvaluateProjectFileCore(String
>   filePath) in
>   C:\projects\omnisharp-roslyn\src\OmniSharp.MSBuild\ProjectLoader.cs:line
>   129    at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader.BuildProject(String
>   filePath) in
>   C:\projects\omnisharp-roslyn\src\OmniSharp.MSBuild\ProjectLoader.cs:line
>   72    at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectFile.ProjectFileInfo.Load(String
>   filePath, ProjectIdInfo projectIdInfo, ProjectLoader loader) in
>   C:\projects\omnisharp-roslyn\src\OmniSharp.MSBuild\ProjectFile\ProjectFileInfo.cs:line
>   95    at
>   OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager.<>c__DisplayClass29_0.<LoadProject>b__0()
>   in
>   C:\projects\omnisharp-roslyn\src\OmniSharp.MSBuild\ProjectManager.cs:line
>   297    at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager.LoadOrReloadProject(String
>   projectFilePath, Func`1 loader) in
>   C:\projects\omnisharp-roslyn\src\OmniSharp.MSBuild\ProjectManager.cs:line
>   308

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very straight-forward. You have a `global.json` either in your home directory or some path relative to your solution or project, which is set to use 1.0.4 of the .NET Core SDK/runtime. You don't have 1.0.4 installed, so you get the error. The `global.json` file affects *all* uses of `dotnet`, so attempt to gen a new `global.json` is going to fail as well.

Simply, you just need to find the existing file and manually change the version to one you *do* have installed, or just remove it entirely, allowing the latest installed SDK/runtime version to become the default.

Comment: was a little bit stupid do not see such a evident thing

Answer (score 1):

> A compatible SDK version for global.json version: [1.0.4] from
>   [C:\Learning\MS-Certif-20-487\AzureToolkit\global.json] was not found

As this error indicates and the suggestion, there is a `global.json` in your path `C:\Learning\MS-Certif-20-487\AzureToolkit\`. Remove it manually.

It seems you are using repository [AzureToolkit](https://github.com/geoffmmorgan/AzureToolkit), for this project, it targets to `netcoreapp1.1`. If you are learning `Azure Storage APIs for .NET`, I would suggest you get started from [Azure Storage APIs for .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/storage?view=azure-dotnet) by creating your own asp.net core project, instead of cloning the existing project with old .net core version. You may hit other issues since you may not be familiar with Asp.NET Core and SPA project template.